# Grid clipping issue in Layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, clip, layouts, grids-graticules

I'm having an issue making a figure for a poster with ArcMap.  I'm trying to make a grid that follows the map boundary in a Lambert Conical projection, and it's not coming out right.  The map boundary is a layer in my data frame, and I'm trying to clip the grid to that.  Everything except the bottom grid is working properly and I can't figure out how to fix it.  I've attached a screenshot for reference.[image: clipping_problem]

Comment: I don't know if it will work but there's a setting in the AdvancedArcMapSettings program (installation folder, Utilities) that changes the densification of the graticule lines. It's the data frame tab, Graticule Densification. You have to have super user permission to use this utility.

Comment: Would I need to reload arcmap after changing those settings?  or just make a new grid in the data frame properties?

Comment: Hrm, I do not think you need to restart ArcMap but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I played with it a little bit without closing arc and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The Advanced ArcMap Settings Utility tells you to restart ArcMap after changing settings - "If ArcMap is running, you must restart it in order for your changes to take effect." -  If you don't restart ArcMap your changes won't be reflected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with the map boundary layer.  My adviser suggested loading it with the relevant layers into a blank document and the map boundary was the only layer that wouldn't load in.

I managed to work around the issue by making a giant polygon of all my geologic units and clipping the extent to that polygon since my map units all terminate at that 50S parallel.

I'm not sure what changing the graticule density would have helped with, but hey, now I can make my poster.